# What does $F^2_n$ mean?

Tags: number-theory, notation, fibonacci-numbers

In this [Wikipedia entry on Cassini's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini%27s_identity), I saw this equation:

$F_{n-1}F_{n+1}-F^2_n=(-1)^n$

$F^2_n$, what does that mean? Is it a summation signs for n to 2? I don't know what it means.

Comment: It's the number $F_n$ to the power of $2$.

Comment: ah ok thanks you could have answered instead

Answer (score 4):

$F_n^2$ is the square of the $n^{\text{th}}$ Fibonacci number.